# Show placeholder text in empty input fields

Tags: javascript, css

How it is possible that during `onfocus` (on input field) input default value seen like it is disabled but on input field could be written anything like default value isn't exists ?

here is simple html =>

```
<input type="text" id="x">
```

and javascript =>

```
document.getElementById("x").onfocus = function(){
this.style.opacity = 0.5;
}
```

but I couldn't do what I want.

Comment: I've tried a lot you know , and just do not written because it is really very simple , but can't solved it. I'll updated my question and please help if you can

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With "HTML5", new functionality and attributes have been introduced for form-Elements (such as built-in form-validation for example)

One of those is the `placeholder` - attribute. It shows a specified text on empty input-Fields that will be hidden, after a user starts to fill text in the field. 
The HTML-Markup looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Fill in your name">
```

This feature is not supported by all browsers yet (you can check compatibility on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder)

In your code, you can check for compatibility with a simple function:

```
var placeHolderSupport = ('placeholder' in document.createElement('input'));
```

For older browsers, you would need to write a fallback JavaScript - Function, that reads this attribute and implement the behaviour yourselve. There are some blog-posts about this around the web, like one from [David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder), that could help you with this.

**edit**:

I stumbled over this [gist](https://gist.github.com/379601) by Hagenburger ([according blog-post](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html)), that should implement the behaviour you want to achieve for old browsers too. **Note**: it's jQuery - code, not sure if you are using it, but even if not, it should give you an idea, what to do.

So, given the compatibility - check from above:

```
if(!placeHolderSupport){
    //gist code here (not sure if i'm allowed to copy this into my answer)
}
```

Like that, the native placeholder-implementation of the browser would be used, if it exists, otherwise, the JavaScript-function would take care of this.

**update 09/11/2012**

SO-User and Moderator ThiefMaster just pointed out a better and newer jQuery-plugin by Mathias Bynens, that already has built-in check for `placeholder` - support. Surely a better way to implement the placeholder-fallback than the gist I posted:

[jQuery Placeholder at github](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="blah" name="Email"
 id="Email" onblur="this.value = 'blah';"
 onfocus="this.value = 'blah';" />
```

Comment: I know this , but you can not get the question well , to explain exactly I mean like it is on Facebook search field, when input is onfocused default text become dim and be seen but the pointer of cursor be at the beginning of  input

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" data-placeholder="Name" />


$(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).val($(this).data('placeholder'));
    }
});

});
$('input').focusin(function(){
    if($(this).val() == $(this).data('placeholder')){
        $(this).val('');
    }
}).focusout(function(){    
    if($(this).val().length < 0){
        $(this).val($(this).data('placeholder'));
    }
})​;​
```

See example quick and dirty [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/SkRN9/2/).